# Not able to read valid voltage input in raspberry pi with PCF8591

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I try to read voltage input came form machine via PCF8591 in Raspberry-pi using I2C communication but printing some another value.

Also could you please suggest me for I want to get machine input voltage if voltage is dropped it should interrupt a function which method should I use?

**Connection between PCF8591-> Raspberry Pi**

1. SDL -> SDL on Rpi
2. SCL -> SCL on Rpi
3. VCC -> 3.3v on Rpi even tried 5.0v
4. GND -> GND on Rpi

**Connection machine to PCF8591**

1. 5v -> AIN1 on PCF8591
2. GND -> GND Rpi

   `import smbus
   import time
   address = 0x48
   A0 = 0x40
   A1 = 0x41
   A2 = 0x42
   A3 = 0x43
   bus = smbus.SMBus(1)
   while True:
       bus.read_byte_data(address,A1)
       value = bus.read_byte_data(address, A1)
       print("AOUT: %1.03f" %(value*3.3/255))
       time.sleep(0.2)`

Showing output like this
AOUT: 2.756

Comment: ```enter code here`bus.write_byte(address,A1)``` please correct that

Comment: @nitesh-waghmare According to the datasheet (https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/data-sheet/PCF8591.pdf) you need to connect your inputsignal to the **AIN1** pin (pin number 2) and not to the A1 pin (pin number 6)! The A0-A2 pins are there to change the i2c address. Further more the Inputvoltage at AIN0-3 has to be in range 0V-Vcc. On an Raspberry Pi you should use the 3.3V as Vcc to not harm the SDA and SCL inputs on it and a voltage divider on the AIN0-3 pins.

Comment: @SebastianStigler Sorry in my PFC8591 have only five pins AOUT,AIN0-AIN3 so I Connected to AIN1 pin

Comment: @nitesh-waghmare Ok. But keep in mind, that  `value*3.3/255` results in values between 0 and 3.3!

Answer (score 0):

To get the correct value, you have to read the value twice. The first read tells the chip to do a new measurement and return meanwhile the current value in the register (which is not the correct value). On the second read you get the correct value:

```
import smbus
import time

address = 0x48  
A0 = 0x40
A1 = 0x41
A2 = 0x42
A3 = 0x43
bus = smbus.SMBus(1)

while True:
    bus.read_byte_data(address, A1)  # do the measurement but ignore the value
    value = bus.read_byte_data(address, A1)  # get the correct value
    #print(value)
    print("AOUT: %1.03f" %(value*3.3/255))
    time.sleep(0.2)
```

Comment: I Tried this but still not able to get correct input and one thing am I doing correct connection please check